# How to grab class names and attributes from ajax loaded html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I am loading pages via ajax and need to grab a certain class from the parsed html. The method I'm using doesn't seem to work and only returns 'undefined'.

```
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:"path/to/page",
    success:function(r){
      r = $(r);//parse html
      var page = r.find('#siteWrap').attr('class');//pull off class name
      alert(page);//returns "undefined"
    }
  });
```

Love some help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solution I came up with (inspired by @helle):

I put a new element on the page I am requesting,

```
<div id='page' style='display:none;'>myPage</div>
```

I then use jQuery to pull the html out from between those tags in the response data:

```
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:$path,
    data:{ajaxRequest:'true'},
    success:function(r){
      var $r = $(r);
      var $page = $r.find('#page').html();
      alert($page);//alerts "myPage"!
    }
  });
```

Conclusion:
You can not pull attributes or class names from ajax html responses once parsed by jquery, only html() can be pull out of parsed html data.

Hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score 3):

try to add your data (`r`) to the dom:

`$(body).append('<div id="appended">'+r+'</div>);`  and then do something like this:
`$('#appended').find(....)`

if you want to not show the data in R just hide `#appended` via css i.e. `#appended{display: none;}` and remove it after your parsing `$('#appended').remove()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just a typo; try changing the $r.find to r.find

Comment: Typo corrected. Only evident on forum post. Not reason for problem.

Comment: do you have any console log messages?  perhaps the target url is not allowed cross-domain, or the resource cannot be accessed.  i've tested your example and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like $r is undefined.

```
r = $(r);//parse html
```

`$r` is still `undefined`.

Comment: Typo corrected. Only evident on forum post. Not reason for problem.